# Invalid column name userId error occur while updating database using Repeater Command Argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Here is Asp.net button code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Approved Job Request" CssClass="css_button" CommandName="ApplyButton" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AId")%>' />
```

Here is C# code

```
 if (e.CommandName == "ApplyButton")
    {
        int userId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mrunal;Initial Catalog=JobPortalDB;Integrated Security=True");

        String sql = "update AppliedJob set AApprove='yes' where AId=userId";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("~/ReqHome.aspx");
    }
```

With above code, getting error as

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'userId'

.
What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your condition in update clause is not correct

You can do like:

```
 String sql = "update AppliedJob set AApprove='yes' where AId='"+userId+"'";
```

But the above is not power with SQL injection, I hardly recommend use SQL parameters so
Try this:

```
 int userId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
 String sql = "update AppliedJob set AApprove='yes' where AId=@userId";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
```

Comment: Are you sure the cause of the error is that line, or do you have SQL command somewhere else ? make sure.

Comment: working with `String sql = "update AppliedJob set AApprove='yes' where AId='"+userId+"'"`